# After drawing the scene with the deferred shader, I want to draw an object to be alpha blended, but it doesn't work

Tags: directx11, alpha-blending

After drawing the scene with the deferred shader, I want to draw an object to be alpha blended, but it doesn't work.

This is the current drawing order

```
void Renderer::Render()
{
    RenderPriority();

    RenderNonAlpha();

    RenderLight();

    RenderBlend();

    RenderAlpha();

    RenderUI();


}
```

In render blend, I draw non alphas, draw the texture on the back buffer, and then draw the objects to be alpha blended.

```
void Renderer::RenderBlend()
{
    //deferredBuffer->BeginMRT(L"Blend");


    // 모든 2D 렌더링을 시작하려면 Z 버퍼를 끕니다.
    Graphic->TurnZBufferOff();

    blendShader->Render();

    auto diffuse = deferredBuffer->GetShaderResourceView(DeferredBuffer::DIFFUSEMAP);
    auto shade = deferredBuffer->GetShaderResourceView(DeferredBuffer::SHADE);
    auto specular = deferredBuffer->GetShaderResourceView(DeferredBuffer::SPECULAR);


    Graphic->GetDeviceContext()->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &diffuse);
    Graphic->GetDeviceContext()->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &shade);
    Graphic->GetDeviceContext()->PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, &specular);



    //transform->Render();
    rectangleBuffer->Render();


    //deferredBuffer->Render();



    //deferredBuffer->EndMRT();

    // 모든 2D 렌더링이 완료되었으므로 Z 버퍼를 다시 켜십시오.
    Graphic->TurnZBufferOn();

}
```

this for render alpha code

```
void Renderer::RenderAlpha()
{
    RenderGroup[RENDER_ALPHA].sort(Compare);

    //Graphic->TurnZBufferOff();
    Graphic->TurnOnAlphaBlending();
    for (auto& pGameObject : RenderGroup[RENDER_ALPHA])
    {

        if (nullptr != pGameObject)
        {

            pGameObject->RenderDepthForShadow(false);
            pGameObject->Render();

        }
    }




    RenderGroup[RENDER_ALPHA].clear();
    Graphic->TurnOffAlphaBlending();
    //Graphic->TurnZBufferOn();

}
```

I want to make the object being alpha blended to be covered, but it is not covered even though the terrain is in front like the picture shown.

[image]

I know that it comes out like the above because I draw the objects to be alpha blended after drawing the texture of the non alpha object (such as terrain) in the back buffer, but is there a way to make the objects to be alpha blended according to the visible position obscured?

Comment: It looks like you're disabling the depth buffer here: `Graphic->TurnZBufferOff()` It's conventional to disable depth *writing* for alpha blended content, but are you also disabling depth *reading*, ie. z testing?

Comment: Do you mean to remove TurnZBufferOff(), TurnZBufferOn() in render blend and compare the depth with the texture drawn in the backbuffer in render alpha?